# How to combine two commands to get one output using command prompt

Tags: cmd

I have a folder on a shared network drive with a large number of text files. I am required to list the file name, size and number of lines/ rows in each file. I am able to use command prompt to get the output separately but I cannot seem to combine.

This works perfectly to list the file name and size:

```
DIR /s “files location*.txt” > Directory.txt
```

This works to for the line count:

```
for %f in ("files location*.txt" ) do find /v /c "" "%f"
```

I tried the following to combine but the output was empty and the command prompt window showed the full file location and name but without the line count

```
DIR /s “files location*.txt” | for %f in (“files location*.txt”) do find /v /c "" "%f" > Directory.txt
```

Comment: `(dir /S "files location*.txt" & for %f in ("files location*.txt") do find /V /C "" "%~f") > "Directory.txt"`? The pipe `|` is wrong here as it passes the output of one command into the input of another one. Do you really want `dir /S` but not `for /R`? *N. B.:* I hope you are having straight quotes in your code rather than typographical ones…

Comment: I tried (For /R  “files location” %g IN (*.txt) do type "%g") | find /c /v ""  as well but nothing happened. I also tried   set file= files location *.txt
set /a cnt=0
(
 For /r do (
  for /r “files location *.txt” %a in ('type "%f"^|find /C /v  "" ') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo %file% has %cnt% lines)
)>>list.txt

GOTO :EOF   I got an error that the file location is not recognized as an internal or external command. files location*.txt was wrapped in quotes as the file path contained spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question has been here before. Put these two (2) files into the same directory. The directory should be in the PATH variable. Many things could be done to make this more flexible using parameters. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available. If you have PowerShell 6 or higher, change `powershell` to `pwsh`.

=== Get-FileLineCount.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "%~dp0Get-FileListCount.ps1"
EXIT /B
```

=== Get-FileLineCount.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t' -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
            Length = $_.Length
            LineCount = (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count
            FileName = $_.FullName
        }
    }
```

This produces the following output.

```
LastWriteTime         Length LineCount FileName
-------------         ------ --------- --------
2021-04-08 08:14:59        3         1 C:\src\t\abc.txt
2021-04-08 08:16:39        8         1 C:\src\t\abc-utf-8.txt
2019-07-08 11:38:36       30         1 C:\src\t\append.txt
2019-07-08 11:38:36       36        12 C:\src\t\appendtemp.txt
2020-03-06 09:48:51      104        25 C:\src\t\Combined.txt
```

Comment: I tried the powershell method above and it works but what I require is the file name, size and line count. This only gives the file name and line count

Comment: @LenC, Length is added.